# Calculating the redshift of each dot/ galaxy/ star in an image and measure its distance

Tags: python

I am writing a code to calculate and measure the distance of a star/ galaxy based on its redshift, the code is yeilding an empty plotline, can someone tell me why?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\[Name]\Desktop\Space Pictures\STScI-01G8H49RQ0E48YDM8WKW9PP5XS.png")

colors = []
redshifts = []

distances = []
for color, redshift in zip(colors, redshifts):
    distance = calculate_distance(color, redshift)
    distances.append(distance)

plt.scatter(colors, distances)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code written above only declares the colors and redshifts lists, and are empty, so it doesn't actually do anything in the for loop, and so when you go to plot, you're plotting nothing.